# How to represent an accounting document in a single row?

Tags: python, pandas, accounting

I'm working on a data science project involving accounting documents. I'm not an accountant but to my understanding, an accounting document is comprised of a set of credits and a set of debits, the total of which are called line items.

This in turn means that each accounting document has a variable number of line items and occupies several lines in a pandas dataframe, .xlsx file, etc. If we try to represent an accounting document in a single row, then there would be dimension mismatch, since each accounting doc. will have different number of line items.

Example:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Credit(1)/Debit(0) Indicator</th>
        <th>Account</th>
        <th>Document ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>00001</td>
        <td>999999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>00020</td>
        <td>999999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>00010</td>
        <td>999999</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>00005</td>
        <td>999999</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this example, we have an accounting doc. where 1 account has been credited and 3 accounts that where debited. This is a total of 4 line items.

The question is, is there a way to represent this information in 1 line without dimension mismatch? The accounting doc. id can be used to group line items. The dimension mismatch comes as a result of the different number of line items of each accounting doc.

Comment: You better create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise it is very difficult to answer your question in SO. Eg. it is very difficult to see how a _single row_ would look like. There might be some ways to give you hints, but give first an example.

Comment: @YannisP. is this example satisfactory?

Comment: it was a bit more clear, but cannot really see now how do you intend to group. When saying _accounting doc. id can be used to group line items_, are you actually grouping by the column `Document ID`? Then you solution can be something like `data.pivot_table(index=['Document ID', 'Credit(1)/Debit(0) Indicator'])`, where `data` is your DataFrame. The default aggregate function here is `mean`, but this can be parametrized. Check also the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table)